# cannot traverse the nodes of an AST, while assigning each node an ID

Tags: rascal

This is more a simple personal attempt to understand what goes on inside Rascal. There must be better (if not already supported) solution.
Here's the code:

```
fileLoad = |home:///PHPAnalysis/systems/ApilTestScripts/simple1.php|;
fileAST=loadPHPFile(fileLoad,true,false);

//assign a simple id to each node
public map[value,int] assignID12(node N)
{
    myID=();
    visit(N)
    {
        case node M:
        {
            name=getName(M);
            myID[name] =999;

        }
    }
return myID;
}

ids=assignID12(fileAST);
```

gives me

```
|stdin:///|(92,4,<1,92>,<1,96>): Expected str, but got value
```

loadPHPFile returns a node of type: list[Stmt], where each Stmt is one of the many types of statements that could occur in a program (PHP, in my case). Without going into why I'd do this, why doesn't the above code work? Especially frustrating because a very simple example is worked out in the online documentation. See: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Recipes/Basic/Basic.html#/Recipes/Common/CountConstructors/CountConstructors.html

Answer (score 0):

I started a new console, and it seems to work. Of course, I changed the return type from map[value,int] to map[str,int] as it was originally in the example.

The problem I was having was that I may have erroneously defined the function previously. While I quickly fixed an apparent problem, it kept giving me errors. I realized that in Rascal, when you've started a console and imported certain definitions, it (seems)is impossible to overwrite those definitions. The interpreter keeps making reference to the very first definition that you provided. This could just be the interpreter performing a type-check, and preventing unintentional and/or incompatible assignments further down the road. That makes sense for variables (in the typical program sense), but it doesn't seem like the best idea to enforce that on functions (or methods). I feel it becomes cumbersome, because a user typically has to undergo some iterations before he/she is satisfied with a function definition. Just my opinion though...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you already had the name `ids` in scope as having type `map[str,int]`, which would be the direct source of the error. You can look in script https://github.com/cwi-swat/php-analysis/blob/master/src/lang/php/analysis/cfg/LabelState.rsc at the function `labelScript` to see how this is done in PHP AiR (so you don't need to write this code yourself). What this will give you is a script where all the expressions and statements have an assigned ID, as well as the label state, which just keeps track of some info used in this labeling operation (mainly the counter to generate a unique ID).

As for the earlier response, the best thing to do is to give your definitions in modules which you can import. If you do that, any changes to types, etc will be picked up (automatically if the module is already imported, since Rascal will reimport the module for you if it has changed, or when you next import the module). However, if you define something directly in the console, this won't happen. Think of the console as one large module that you keep adding to. Since we can have overloads of functions, if you define the function again you are really defining a new alternative to the function, but this may not work like you expect.